# Clearing past drawings on javafx using timeline

Tags: javafx

I am trying to make a snake game using maven project on JavaFX. In my code snake was moving but the previous coordinates are not cleared on the scene. Are there any solution for this? Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

int sceneX = 600;
int sceneY = 400;
ArrayList <Point> snake = new ArrayList<>();
private GraphicsContext gc;

private void run(GraphicsContext gc) {  
    drawSnake(gc);
    for (int i = snake.size()-1; i>=1; i--) {
        snake.get(i).x = snake.get(i - 1).x;
        snake.get(i).y = snake.get(i - 1).y;
    }
    snake.get(0).x++;
}

private void drawSnake(GraphicsContext gc) {
    for (int i =0; i<3; i++) {
        gc.fillRoundRect(snake.get(i).getX(), snake.get(i).getY(),5,5,3,3);
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("SNAKE");
    Group root = new Group();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(sceneX, sceneY);
    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    Scene scene = new Scene (root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        snake.add(new Point(300, 300));
    }
    
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(130), e -> run(gc)));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();   

}
```

Comment: You have two options: a -> replace canvas with the scene graph and remove elements that are no longer needed from the scene graph OR b -> keep the canvas and clear it, repainting each frame.  The [canvas tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/canvas.htm) has info on clearing portions of the canvas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but opt b not worked for me. just clear one direction, when I change the direction other side its fails again or leave tiny point on screen. Can you explain a little more the opt a, I don't understand what you mean of "replace canvas with scene graph"

Comment: Here is an Oracle tutorial on [working with the scene graph](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/scene-graph-tutorial/scenegraph.htm#sthref8).  As noted, using the canvas or the scene graph are different options for accomplishing the same thing.  When coded correctly either approach will work, with different kinds of work required for each approach.  Often, in my experience, it is easier to work with the Scene Graph rather than a canvas.  However, which to choose depends on your preference, experience, design, and requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with what @jewelsea mentioned in the comments.

If you don't have very complex drawings/painting on the canvas, I think using scenegraph approach should make things simple.

If you opt for canvas, one possible drawback I can think of is : you need to redraw the entire canvas. Because clearing only part of the rectangle will not be a solution if you have some layered drawings (like background.. etc)

```
private void run(GraphicsContext gc) {
    for (int i = 0; i < snake.size(); i++) {
        gc.clearRect(snake.get(i).x, snake.get(i).y, size, size);
    }
    int lastIndex = snake.size() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
        snake.get(i).x = snake.get(i + 1).x;
    }
    snake.get(lastIndex).x += size;
    drawSnake(gc);
}
```

In the below gif for canvas approach, clearing the snake alone is not sufficient if I have some background.

[image]

On the other hand, if I use scenegraph approach, once we include the building blocks of the snake, all we need to do is to update the position of the building blocks.

```
private void run() {
    int lastIndex = shapes.size() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
        shapes.get(i).setLayoutX(shapes.get(i + 1).getLayoutX());
    }
    shapes.get(lastIndex).setLayoutX(shapes.get(lastIndex).getLayoutX() + size);
}
```

Below is the complete demo differentiating the two approaches:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SnakeGameDemo extends Application {

    int width = 300;
    int height = 200;
    int startX = 100;
    int startY = 100;
    int size = 5;
    int speed = 250;
    List<Point> snake = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Rectangle> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("SNAKE");
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setHgap(10);
        root.setVgap(10);
        root.addRow(0, new Label("Canvas"), new Label("SceneGraph"));
        root.addRow(1, canvasApproach(), scenegraphApproach());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Node canvasApproach() {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(width, height);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.RED);
        gc.fillRoundRect(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0);
        gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            snake.add(new Point(startX + (i * size), startY));
        }

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(speed), e -> run(gc)));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
        return canvas;
    }

    private void run(GraphicsContext gc) {
        for (int i = 0; i < snake.size(); i++) {
            gc.clearRect(snake.get(i).x, snake.get(i).y, size, size);
        }
        int lastIndex = snake.size() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
            snake.get(i).x = snake.get(i + 1).x;
        }
        snake.get(lastIndex).x += size;
        drawSnake(gc);
    }

    private void drawSnake(GraphicsContext gc) {
        snake.forEach(block -> {
            gc.fillRoundRect(block.getX(), block.getY(), size, size, 3, 3);
        });
    }

    private Node scenegraphApproach() {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red;");
        pane.setPrefSize(width, height);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Rectangle block = new Rectangle(size, size, Color.GREEN);
            // Position the shapes in the Pane using the layoutX/Y properties.
            block.setLayoutX(startX + (i * size));
            block.setLayoutY(startY);
            pane.getChildren().add(block);
            shapes.add(block);
        }

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(speed), e -> run()));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
        return pane;
    }

    private void run() {
        int lastIndex = shapes.size() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
            shapes.get(i).setLayoutX(shapes.get(i + 1).getLayoutX());
        }
        shapes.get(lastIndex).setLayoutX(shapes.get(lastIndex).getLayoutX() + size);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this instance, but my preference would be to use a [javafx.geometry.Point2D](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/geometry/Point2D.html) rather than a [java.awt.Point](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.desktop/java/awt/Point.html).